# Fisher Forecasting Using Mathematica

Tags: probability-or-statistics, packages, physics

I'm need to do a Fisher Forecast for my experimental physics requirements. I'm trying to constrain parameter for a modified Friedmann equation. Is there any package or code that any of you have handy that can generate the Fisher Information Matrix. Also how long from your experience does it to do a Fisher Forecast. I really need to do this by the end of the month. I already have Likelihood and constrained parameters from past experiments.

Thank you all very much.

Comment: The `Likelihood` and `LogLikelihood` functions along with `D` (the derivative function) can obtain symbolic and numeric estimates of the Fisher Information Matrix.  If you show what you've already done in *Mathematica*, then you'd likely receive more specific help.  You'll also get more help if you start accepting answers on your other questions when you deem the answers acceptable.

Comment: What do you mean by accepting answers? Is there a button I'm supposed to press to indicate that I accepted an answer?

Comment: See https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers.

Comment: There I think I clicked on the check marks and accepted those truly helpful answer that allowed me to finish the first part of my project.

Comment: Very good.  One last thing: if you were the one who posted https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/how-to-do-fisher-forecasting-for-constraining-parameters.917135/, then you should mention that you've simultaneously posted the same question elsewhere.  If that's not you, I'll remove this comment.

Comment: Yes I posted it on physics forum as well.